# why the output of the Hashmap is arbitary, not in a specific order? why its sorting order gets change on insertion & deletion of new node?

Tags: data-structures, hashmap

Please explain why the hashmap gives unpredictable output? On which basis it sorts the elements ? why its output changes when we insert / delete a new element?
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Set;

```
    public class Main6 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            HashMap<String, String> hMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

            hMap.put("10", "One");
            hMap.put("11", "Two");
            hMap.put("12", "Three"); 
            hMap.put("17", "simran");
            hMap.put("13", "four");
            hMap.put("14", "five");

            Set st = hMap.keySet();
            //st.remove("12");
            Iterator itr = st.iterator();

            while (itr.hasNext())
            System.out.println(itr.next());

            // remove 2 from Set
                //st.remove("12");


            System.out.println(hMap.containsKey("12"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Read up on hashmaps first (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashmap).  Hopefully then you'll understand the unpredictable ordering.

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` iteration order depends on how the object hashes are distributed among the buckets. When you add a new item, the number of buckets may be expanded, which will require the entries to be redistributed, which will reorder everything.

Also, as a security measure, current implementations of `HashMap` have a randomised hashing mode (["alternative hashing"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/changes7.html)) which is enabled after a certain threshold (`jdk.map.althashing.threshold`). This is to thwart a certain class of denial-of-service attacks which involve trying to find hash collisions.